# Exception handling for twitter gem when tweet id NotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm very new to writing exception handling and I'm unsure on how to solve this particular handling.

I save multiple tweets in my table, to shorten down on the calls to Twitter. I also allow the user to favorite these tweet through my app.

However if that tweet has been deleted the error that appears is

```
(Twitter::Error::NotFound) — Error raised when tweet does not exist or has been deleted.
```

What I'd like to do is, if I get that error I'd like to delete the tweet from my table.

Here's my code:

```
def favorite
  not_favorited = self.favorites.where(favorited: false)
  not_favorited_ids = not_favorited.map(&:id)
  tweet_ids = not_favorited.map(&:tweet_id)
  begin
    Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(favorited: true) && self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids)
  rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => e
    # if tweet is not found, then delete the tweet from the favorites
  rescue Twitter::Error::AlreadyFavorited => e

  rescue Twitter::Error::Unauthorized => e
    logger.error "Unauthorized access"
  rescue => e
  end
end
```

So as you see I have the rescue up for Error::NotFound, but I'm not sure how to write a piece of code that gets that specific id and goes ahead and deletes it, before continuing the process.

Answer (score 0):

[`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) does not return any meaningful information about which records were successfully updated, and which records raised an error.

Since you want to handle failures for each failed updates, best to do the update one tweet at a time.

The code would be similar to the following:

```
Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).each do |tweet|
  begin
     Favorite.update(tweet.id, favorited: true)
     self.twitter.favorite!(tweet.id)
  rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => e
     # if tweet is not found, then delete the tweet from the favorites using tweet.id
  end
end
```

Probably a good idea to rewrite the `favorite` method logic to work with one tweet at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfavorite a tweet that does not exist. The object is gone. When you destroy_status, the tweet is just gone. There is nothing to unfavorite.